# how to get to the root of a directory

Tags: linux, bash, git

I am trying to compile a package in bash and the instructions in github says that:

> Switch to the root of the Phrasal repository and execute: gradle
>   installDist

I tried to determine the root using "hg root". But I get the output as

> abort: no repository found in '/mnt/f/Projects/phrasal' (.hg
>   not found)!

How do I find the root of the directory phrasal? Thanks!!!

Comment: Is `/mnt/f/Projects/phrasal` a clone of the github repository?  If so, then you need to run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to get the root directory of a git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root directory is the first or top-most directory in a hierarchy.

try this:

```
cd /mnt/f/Projects/phrasal
```

then

```
gradle installDist
```